# H2O Driverless AI Ubuntu DEB installation - Fail to load http://localhost:12345

Tags: ubuntu, h2o, driverless-ai

I'm using Ubuntu v16.04.5 as a guest VMWARE in my PC. Below is the installation and status log whereby when I use the Firefox browser to open http://localhost:12345 , no page is displayed (Page not found). However, if I changed the URL to http://localhost:54321 I can see the H2o flow SW displayed in the browser.

I have started the installation using the command

```
$sudo dpkg -i dai_1.3.0_amd64.deb
```

and

```
$sudo DAI_USER=ubuntu DAI_GROUP=root dpkg -i dai_1.3.0_amd64.deb
```

in a separate Ubuntu v16.04.5 fresh VMWARE (guest). After that, I run the following command to start H2o driverless:

```
# Start Driverless AI.
sudo systemctl start dai
```

[H2O AI driverless UBUNTU DEB installation and status log](https://textuploader.com/dv9lg)

I have also try enabling port 12345 in /etc/dai/config.toml file below and restart but the same problem still occur.

[/etc/dai/config.toml](https://textuploader.com/dv9q9)

How can I get this H2o driverless working?

Answer (score 2):

Note that I haven’t seen anybody do exactly this, but I don’t know of any reason why it should not work.  Driverless AI runs fine in a docker container on Windows 10, which I believe is virtualbox underneath.

From the logs, it looks like you probably started the guest OS with only 2 GB of RAM.  This just isn’t enough.

Give the guest at least 8 GB of RAM at the absolute rock-bottom minimum even just to run toy examples.

I don’t expect that to be a “good” experience, but chances are it will at least run.

Comment: After upgrading in another machine with more than 8GB ram, I am not able to start the application. Please refer to screenshot below [LINK] https://ibb.co/hLiQ4p

Comment: Use journalctl to look at the more detailed logs.  'journalctl -u dai-dai'.  Hopefully that will give you better clues about why it didn't work.

Comment: The log show exit as shown below [LINK] http://freetexthost.com/uej1ihln43